# MATLAB: Multiply polynomial coefficient with exponent

Tags: matlab

Given a polynomial in t and it's inverse, I want to figure out a way in MATLAB to implement the following function (the polynomial is defined using syms):

From c1*t^(x1)+c2*t^(x2)+...+cn*t^(xn), get c1*x1+c2*x2+...+cn*xn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `y = c1*t^(x1)+c2*t^(x2)+...+cn*t^(xn)`, maybe you can use the following code

```
yt = diff(y);
k = subs(yt, t,1)
```

This is actually a calculus problem, you can use the property that

```
y'(t) = c1*x1*t^(x1-1) + c2*x2*t^(x2-1) + ... cn*xn*t^(xn-1)
```

and then evaluate `y'(t)` with `t=1`

Comment: Ah, see what you did there. Thank you!

Comment: @user8253417 does this address your problem?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks again.